# mypy check fails when chaining functions annotated with ParamSpec

Tags: python, mypy, typing

If I define two functions which take another function and its parameters as an argument and a simple function as follows

```py
from typing import Callable, TypeVar, ParamSpec

T1 = TypeVar('T1')
P1 = ParamSpec('P1')
T2 = TypeVar('T2')
P2 = ParamSpec('P2')


def wrapper1(
        func: Callable[P1, T1],
        *args: P1.args,
        **kwargs: P1.kwargs
) -> T1:
    return func(*args, **kwargs)


def wrapper2(
        func: Callable[P2, T2],
        *args: P2.args,
        **kwargs: P2.kwargs
) -> T2:
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

def func() -> int:
    return 1
```

and I try to chain these three functions like this

```py
wrapper1(wrapper2, func)
```

then mypy reports the following error on this chain of calls:

```
src/test.py:29: error: Argument 1 to "wrapper1" has incompatible type "Callable[[Arg(Callable[P2, T2], 'func'), **P2], T2]"; expected "Callable[[Arg(Callable[P2, T2], 'func'), **P2], T2]"  [arg-type]
src/test.py:29: error: Argument 2 to "wrapper1" has incompatible type "Callable[[], int]"; expected "[Callable[P2, T2], **P2.args]"  [arg-type]
```

If I avoid chaining the functions like that, then no error is reported by mypy:

```py
def w2() -> int:
    return wrapper2(func)
wrapper1(w2)
```

Is there a way to annotate these functions so that the simple chaining is accepted without having to define a function for the second call?

I am using mypy 1.0.1 and python 3.11.2.

**This seems to be a known problem**:

- https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/13191
- Possibly related to https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/12278

I'm watching those issues now. I'll update this question when these mypy issues are resolved one way or the other.

Comment: It's clearly a `mypy` bug, please look at their issue tracker and report this, if there is no such issue already open. https://github.com/python/mypy/issues

Answer (score 0):

This problem was solved in Version 1.6.0 if mypy is run with `--new-type-inference` (see reference to issue https://github.com/python/mypy/pull/15896 in the release notes https://mypy-lang.blogspot.com/2023/10/mypy-16-released.html). With version 1.7.0 `--new-type-inference` is not needed anymore for the check to succeed, since the new type inference algorithm is now the default.